# Union query "unable to execute query, invalid operation or syntax using multi-value field"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run the query below and I'm getting:

> unable to execute query, invalid operation or syntax using multi-value field

All columns here are matched up and all the values are of same data type. Can't seem to find info on this online that I understand. Can someone help?

```
SELECT
    fq.fk_spEngineerID,
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID,
    fq.BU,
    fq.fk_spProductTypeID,
    fq.fk_spCompanyID,
    fq.fk_spOfficeID
FROM (
    SELECT
        fk_spEngineerID,
        spQuoteID,
        NULL AS spOrderID,
        BU,
        fk_spProductTypeID,
        fk_spCompanyID,
        fk_spOfficeID
    FROM FactQuote
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        fk_spEngineerID,
        NULL AS spQuoteID,
        spOrderID,
        BU,
        fk_spProductTypeID,
        fk_spCompanyID,
        fk_spOfficeID
    FROM FactOrder
) AS fq
GROUP BY
    fq.fk_spEngineerID,
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID,
    fq.BU,
    fq.fk_spProductTypeID,
    fq.fk_spCompanyID,
    fq.fk_spOfficeID;
```

This query runs difference being the source of data is queries not tables

```
select 
    fq.fk_spEngineerID, 
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID, 
    fq.BU,
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID
From (
    Select 
        fk_spEngineerID, 
        spQuoteID,
        "" as spOrderID, 
        BU, 
        spProductTypeID, 
        fk_spCompanyID, 
        fk_spOfficeID, 
    From QuotestatsSubQuery 
    Union All 
        Select 
        fk_spEngineerID,
        "" as spQuoteID,spOrderID,
         BU, 
        spProductTypeID, 
        fk_spCompanyID, 
        fk_spOfficeID 
    From OrderstatsSubQuery
) as fq 
Group By  
    fq.fk_spEngineerID,
    fq.spQuoteID,
    fq.spOrderID,  
    fq.BU, 
    fq.spProductTypeID, 
    fq.fk_spCompanyID, 
    fq.fk_spOfficeID;
```

Comment: OP - are you still around? There is a syntax error in your bottom query. What is the difference between the two statements? Is second the source for first or vice-versa? Usually this error emerges with complex queries and engine is unable to find the specific error.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

MS Access does not support `UNION` or `UNION ALL` in subqueries.  In my opinion, this is a severe limitation.

Apart from migrating to another database, all you can do is define a view.  The view can contain the `UNION ALL` of the tables, and you can then use the `UNION` in an aggregation query.

Comment: is it not supported in the event I am getting data from tables. In this instance both factorder and factquote are tables. I have another query of very same format that gets the values from 2 queries and that works so is that the issue?

Comment: @M_kul . . . `UNION ALL` is supported, just not in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: too long to comment but i added the query in my original question, the only difference is the first one gets the info from tables while the second one first queries the tables and then the query does the same thing. Strangely though it seems to interpret the ids as strings. Can you explain the difference i'd like to understand for future use

Comment: This is not true, MS Access does allow `UNION` or `UNION ALL` in `FROM/JOIN` clause subqueries.

Comment: @Parfait . . . This may be an old limitation.  I don't strive to keep my MS Access syntax up-to-date, so thank you for the clarification.  Unfortunately, the documentation provides no examples one way or the other.  For instance, a `select` does not include union (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821148.aspx) and a subquery is defined as a `select` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192664.aspx).